# Calculate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} I_n$ knowing that the sequence $(I_n)_{n\ge 2}$ is $I(n) = \int_1^{\sqrt{2}} \sqrt[n] {x^n+x^{n+2}} dx $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

> Calculate
>   $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}   I_n$ knowing that the sequence $(I_n)_{n\ge 2}$ is $I_n = \int_1^{\sqrt{2}} \sqrt[n] {x^n+x^{n+2}} dx $

Now, my attempt was like this :
$\int_1^{\sqrt{2}} \sqrt[n] {x^n(1+x^2)} dx $ and $\int_1^{\sqrt{2}} x\sqrt[n] {1+x^2} dx $ . From here I was thinking to do a substitution like $x=\tan(u)$ and using the formula $1+\tan^2(u)=\sec(u)$ but I don't think this is the way to go . Also, I was thinking that maybe I don't need to evaluate the integral directly and maybe use Dominated convergence theorem . Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: Consider the simple substitution $1+x^2=t^n$

Comment: Didn't notice that ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I_n=\int_{1}^{√2}(x^n+x^{n+2})^{1/n}dx;$

$\int_{1}^{√2}x(1+1^2)^{1/n} \lt I_n \lt \int_{1}^{√2}x(1+(√2)^2)^{1/n}dx;$

$2^{1/n}\int_{1}^{√2}xdx\lt I_n < (1+2)^{1/n}\int_{1}^{√2}xdx.$

Integrate and take the limit.

Used:

$0 \le f(x):=(1+1^2)^{1/n}x  \le x(1+x^2)^{1/n} \le x(1+√2^2)=:g(x),$

then $\int_{1}^{√2}f(x)dx \le I_n \le \int_{1}^{√2}g(x)dx$ (Monotony of Riemann Integral).

Answer (score 1):

$x \sqrt[n]{1+x^2} \leq x \sqrt[n]{1+ \sqrt{2}} \leq x\sqrt[n]{3} \leq 3x$ (on the relevant domain). Thus for the $g_n :=x \sqrt[n]{1+x^2}$ we have $|g_n| \leq g$ where $g = 3x$ is integrable. Thus dominated convergence allows us to take the limit inside the integral. $\lim_n \sqrt[n]{1+x^2} = 1$. You should be able to finish it.